# Applying hclust on a list of distance matrices

Tags: r, matrix, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I have attempted to search for an answer to this but could not find one:

In an attempt to perform clustering specific to each user ID in my dataset (385 of them), I have calculated the Euclidean distances between each user and a geographical distance vector (haversine distance).  However, this has resulted in a list of distance matrices, which I can't seem to figure out how to apply hierarchal clustering to.

Example

## splitting data by user id

```
user_id.split<-split(mydata$geodistancevector,mydata$userid)
```

## calculating euclidean distance for each split

```
split.distances<-lapply(user_id.split,function(x) dist(x,method="euclidean"))

str(split.distances)
```

results in a list of 385, for example

```
    >$ 1  :Class 'dist'  atomic [1:496] 1788.4 24.7 922.2 277.8 873.7 ...
    >.. ..- attr(*, "Size")= int 32
    >.. ..- attr(*, "Diag")= logi FALSE
    >.. ..- attr(*, "Upper")= logi FALSE
    >.. ..- attr(*, "method")= chr "euclidean"
    >``.. ..- attr(*, "call")= language dist(x = x, method = "euclidean")

    >$ 2  :Class 'dist'  atomic (0) 
     .. ..- attr(*, "Size")= int 0
     .. ..- attr(*, "Diag")= logi FALSE
     .. ..- attr(*, "Upper")= logi FALSE
     .. ..- attr(*, "method")= chr "euclidean"
      .. ..- attr(*, "call")= language dist(x = x, method = "euclidean")
```

Etc...

How do I apply hclust on this list of distances? I would like to be able to cut it into 385 (cutree), and bind it back to the original data frame.

thanks!

Comment: Something like `lapply(lapply(split.distances, hclust), cutree)`?

Comment: Thanks for the response!  Could you be a little more specific though?  I am still having trouble running the code (still pretty noob with R).  How can I call the hclust on each individual distance element of the list `$1` to `$385` , and the cut the tree for each distinct subset?

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment; the `lapply` function will take the function (in its second argument), and run it on every element of its first argument.

So to run `hclust` on elements `$1` through `$385` of `split.distances`, we can simply do the following:

```
lapply(split.distances, hclust)
```

This will return another list, where each element is the `hclust` of `$1` through `$385`. So to apply the `cutree` function, we can run `lapply` on the results:

```
hclust.results <- lapply(split.distances, hclust)
cutree.results <- lapply(hclust.results, cutree)
```

In my comment, I nest the function calls, reducing the above to:

```
lapply(lapply(split.distances, hclust), cutree)
```

Comment: Thanks again for following up! really appreciate it.  When I try the code mentioned above, however I get an error message: Must have n>=2 objects to cluster, so I am still unsure if I am missing something.

Comment: It looks like some of your distance matrices are empty (see element 2 in your post).

Comment: so thanks to your helpful response  I have deleted any empty distance matrices `lfull<-split.distances[lapply(split.distances, length) > 0]` and have clustered the list with hclust `hclust.results <- lapply(lfull, hclust)`.  However, I am not sure how to cut the tree (cutree) on the list, as every approach I try I am getting the "invalid 'tree' ('mere' component) error.  Is there a way to cut the tree on the list with lapply?

Comment: It sounds like some of your `split.distances` only have one-two elements. `cutree` will throw that error if it encounters a tree with < 1 merge.